# Shortcode displayed outside form/div

Tags: php, woocommerce

How to use return in the foreach? If I use echo on the function shortcode, the shortcode is displayed outside the form/div

```
function produseselectate() {
     global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

      foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            echo "<b> Boxa:".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Cantitate: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "  Pret: ".$price."<br>";
            
        } 
}
add_shortcode('boxecart', 'produseselectate');
```

If I use return insead of echo, the content from cart table display me corectly, but only the first line and also the first product from the cart.

[Here you can see how is displayed the shortcode outside form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mi79.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first build up the result string in each iteration of the loop, then return the full result string at the end of the function

```
function produseselectate()
{
  global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
  $result = '';

  foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
    $_product = wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());
    $result .= "<b> Boxa:" . $_product->get_title() . '</b>  <br> Cantitate: ' . $values['quantity'] . '<br>';
    $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'], '_price', true);
    $result .= "  Pret: " . $price . "<br>";

  }

  return $result;
}

add_shortcode('boxecart', 'produseselectate');
```